# Swift: Selector name found in current argument registers: release

Tags: ios, swift, crash, hockeyapp

I am getting a crash log that I can't repro with the message:

"Selector name found in current argument registers: release"

I cannot figure out what this means and googling, has not given me any good answers.

It is labeled as 
Exception Type:  SIGTRAP

And the line of code that it is crashing at is:

```
let accentColor = data.AccentColor == nil ? UIColor.blackColor() : data.AccentColor!
```

The same line of code worked in the init() function, but it seems to be crashing at this later point after the user taps a button

This crash is happening a fair amount when I send it out to users, but I can't repro it or figure out what may be causing it.

What does this error message mean and what can I do to fix the issue?

Comment: Are you using Hockey SDK for crash reports?

Comment: Yeah, these crashes are from Hockey SDK

Comment: This is *NOT* an issue with Hockey or its SDK. This is an actual bug in either the app or caused by a bug in the toolchain (Swift compiler/linker). The runtime triggered a `SIGTRAP` signal which the SDK catched and produced a crash report for. You will see a similar crash report created by iOS itself. When removing our SDK you would see the same issue in iOS generated crash reports. @GlennRay what do you mean by "according to them are working as designed". Where is the connection to this issue?

Comment: Yeah I don't think this has anything to do with Hockey SDK, is the error message "Selector name found in current argument registers: release" something that comes from Hockey though? I'm trying to understand what it means so I can figure out where to even look in my code

Answer (score 1):

This does not look like an issue with the HockeySDK but much rather with Swift itself.

I've seen several people having issues with Swift compiler optimizations lately. The issue probably only occurs on Ad-Hoc builds because Xcode uses the `Release` configuration for this which uses a different set of compiler settings.
If you try switching your local build from `Debug` to `Release` too, you should be able to reproduce this issue.

As a workaround, you can disable these optimizations for your Ad-Hoc builds but if this persists, you should probably file a bug with Apple.

Comment: This crash actually continued to show up even after we disabled optimizations for our beta users so we don't think it is related to that. I have tried both release and debug versions and have not gotten this to repro. I will look into filing a bug with apple and see if they can help fix this issue or at least give insight into what the error message means.

Comment: Nope I moved on from the project and we never quite figured out the issue